# Windows cannot find, when running batch command in java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have been trying to run a batch command to open a batch file, but it seems to not be able to find the location. The error I get is

> "Windows cannot find 'C:Program' Make sure you typed the name correctly"

This is the original line in the batch

```
call testrunner.bat -a -f"W:\WebServices Migration Project\crp5\regression results" "W:\WebServices Migration Project\crp5\soapui-project.xml"
```

The Java code

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\Program Files\\SmartBear\\SoapUI-5.2.1\\bin\\testrunner.bat -a -f'W:\\WebServices Migration Project\\crp5\regression results' 'W:\\WebServices\\crp5\\soapui-project.xml'");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of having space in your file path. Try:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "C:\\Program Files\\SmartBear\\SoapUI-5.2.1\\bin\\testrunner.bat" -a -f'W:\\WebServices Migration Project\\crp5\regression results' 'W:\\WebServices\\crp5\\soapui-project.xml'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path has spaces:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\Program Files\\SmartBear\\SoapUI-5.2.1\\bin\\testrunner.bat -a -f'W:\\WebServices Migration Project\\crp5\regression results' 'W:\\WebServices\\crp5\\soapui-project.xml'");
                                                                     ^
```

So you're trying to run a program named `C:\Program`, with arguments `Files\SmartBear\etc...`. The path need to be quoted:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"C:\\Program Files\\SmartBear\\SoapUI-5.2.1\\bin\\testrunner.bat\" -a -f'W:\\WebServices Migration Project\\crp5\regression results' 'W:\\WebServices\\crp5\\soapui-project.xml'");
                                                          ^^-----
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, but now getting a similar error for the other paths. Windows cant find 'w\webservice migration....' 'w\ webservice....'  those other paths are more of an argument  for that testrunner.bat file. One is the location of the xml that the bat will use and the other is the location where it stored the output files. Tried similar things but didn't work how I wanted.